# Vista log in screen is different resolution than after logging in

Tags: windows-vista, resolution, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T400. When I boot the log in screen is 800x600 but after logging in it switches to the correct resolution of 1440x900. All my drivers are up to date. Is there some registry setting for the resolution on the log in screen?

Comment: i have the same problem with a Dell 9 mini. intel graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a driver issue with the switchable graphics. I set it to use only 'Discrete Graphics' in the BIOS and it's working now.

With switchable graphics on, if you went into Display properties, the current display was #3 and the other 3 disabled screens were all 800x600. So I'm assuming it uses whatever resolution monitor #1 is and I couldn't switch the LCD display to be #1 (I have no external monitors attached).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should solve your problems.

http://winhlp.com/node/432

> Found it! Run msconfig.exe, select the
>   "Boot" tab ("Computer opstarten" in
>   Dutch), there is a setting Base video
>   which is quite misleadingly translated
>   Standaardvideo in Dutch. So I had
>   enabled it, hoping to get a nice video
>   movie during startup, but it didn't
>   and I forgot about it.
>
> Windowshelp.microsoft.com tells what
>   it does:
>
> ```
> Boots to the Windows graphical user interface in minimal VGA mode.
> ```
>
> This loads standard VGA drivers
>   instead of display drivers specific to
>   the video hardware on the computer.
>
> So I disabled it and all is well.
>
> Greetings, Peter de Bruin

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I checked that setting and it was unchecked.